# Are LINQ expressions an acceptable way to manipulate data in F#?

Tags: .net, linq, f#, functional-programming, coding-style

I'm a beginner F# programmer. I know that F# is functional, and prefers a style where data is piped through functions, such as `map` and `iter` functions on collections. Still, LINQ expressions offer an alternative, highly readable method for manipulating collections; however, I'm unsure if it is more imperative and defeats the point of using a functional language.

For example, without LINQ:

```
let listOfPrimes n =
    [1UL..n]
    |> List.choose (fun i -> match i with
                             | i when isPrime i -> Some i
                             | _ -> None)
```

While with LINQ, we can do:

```
let listOfPrimes n =
    query {
        for i in [1UL..n] do
        where (isPrime i)
        select i
    }
    |> List.ofSeq
```

I note that we need to transform the resultant sequence to a list when using LINQ. So, what's the practical performance difference? Is LINQ stylistically frowned upon outside of actual database queries? When is it appropriate to manipulate collection data using queries outside of that scenario?

Comment: The even simpler version: `[1UL .. n] |> List.filter isPrime`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is a matter of preference - some people prefer to write code using higher-order functions, some people prefer LINQ-style `query` expressions.

It is worth noting, that there are also *sequence expressions*, which can be seen as simpler version of the `query` syntax. Sequence expressions do not give you easy access to the additional query operators, but they work nicely for simple things and you can also use the `[ ... ]` notation to get the result as lists:

```
let listOfPrimes n =
  [ for i in [1UL..n] do
      if (isPrime i) then yield i ]
```

My personal preference is:

- Use sequence expressions for simple filtering & projection & choosing
- Use higher-order functions for other operations (perhaps with the exception of complex grouping and joining where query expressions are nicer).
- Use query expressions for database access

Comment: I'm reminded that I have seen sequence expressions before, and feel stupid for not having remembered them.

My primary concern was constructing collections of a different type than the one being queried, and both sequence expressions and LINQ solve that problem better than `map`, which only returns collections of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing a `query` on its own, outside of doing interop with C# APIs that expect `IQueryables`, could certainly rise a few eyebrows. But that's mainly because of the already mentioned "native" collection comprehensions that you have available in F# if you want to use a similar syntax.

As for how the different choices compare, I did a little test using the following code:

```
module TestHof = 
    let make n = 
        seq { 1 .. n }
        |> Seq.map (fun x -> x * x)
        |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x > n/2)
        |> Seq.toList

module TestExpr = 
    let make n =
        [ for i in 1 .. n do
              let x = i * i 
              if x > n/2 then yield x ]

module TestSeqExpr = 
    let make n =
        seq { for i in 1 .. n do
                let x = i * i 
                if x > n/2 then yield x }
        |> Seq.toList

module TestQuery =
    let make n =
        query { for i in 1 .. n do
                    select (i * i) into x
                    where (x > n/2) }
        |> Seq.toList
```

and the timings of running them it in FSI were as follows:

```
> TestHof.make 1000000;;
Real: 00:00:00.796, CPU: 00:00:00.781, GC gen0: 3, gen1: 2, gen2: 0    

> TestExpr.make 1000000;;
Real: 00:00:00.613, CPU: 00:00:00.625, GC gen0: 3, gen1: 2, gen2: 0

> TestSeqExpr.make 1000000;;
Real: 00:00:00.563, CPU: 00:00:00.562, GC gen0: 3, gen1: 2, gen2: 0

> TestQuery.make 1000000;;
Real: 00:00:05.638, CPU: 00:00:05.562, GC gen0: 20, gen1: 3, gen2: 0
```

So `query` falls significantly behind the other options.

An interesting observation here is that IL code for a list comprehension (`TestExpr`) and a sequence expression that is later converted to a list (`TestSeqExpr`) is exactly the same. Meaning that a list comprehension is essentially a sequence expression wrapped in a call to `Seq.toList` - something that makes perfect sense, but is not an obvious thing either.

Comment: What about `{ 1 .. n }` rather than `[ 1 .. n ]` in `TestHof`, to avoid the initial list allocation? Or `Seq.init n ((+) 1)`?

Comment: Thank you very much for these insights. List and sequence expressions seem extremely fast and the way to go, though I have no idea how that might scale to more complex types and operations. Turns out, F# had direct and expressive solutions to my problem already. I need to read and learn more!

Comment: @ildjarn: that's a fair point - updated. It makes that case better, but still curiously slower than the alternatives.

Comment: @Nerve: if anything, the overhead will matter less as the operations get more time-consuming. In the end, it really is a matter of readability.

Comment: @scrwtp : I suspect the difference is that Hof has multiple different sequence functions chained together while Expr and SeqExpr generate a _single_ state machine. I haven't looked at the IL though.

Comment: This is what Nessos.Streams gives: A way to keep the expressions separate, but still have the perf.